# The area of a triangle with sides $59,37,12\sqrt5$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is the easiest way to calculate the area of a triangle with sides $59,37,12\sqrt5$?

My try: Let the triangle be $AC_1C$ and $AC_1=59,CC_1=12\sqrt5,AC=37$. My idea was to find the $\cos \measuredangle ACC_1$ (with the hope of it being a right angle). We can then find $\sin\measuredangle ACC_1$ and apply the formula $S_{\triangle AC_1C}=\dfrac12AC\cdot CC_1\sin\measuredangle ACC_1$. The calculations are a mess. The answer is as good as it can get: $354$ Is there another approach?

Comment: Your idea is fine, but you chose the wrong angle: find instead $\cos CAC_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hour ago i just answered a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414018/find-the-area-of-a-triangle-with-vertices-0-1-1-1-1-2-2-3-1), an equivalent version of Heron's formula applies, and the computation is just one line. The formula for the area $A$ of the given triangle can be extracted from:
$$
16A^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)\ ,
$$
in our case we have $a^2=3481$, $b^2=1369$, $c^2=720$, so
$$
16A^2
=(3481+1369+720)^2 -2(3481^2+1369^2+720^2)
=2005056
=16\cdot(2\cdot 3\cdot 59)^2
\ .
$$
So $A=2\cdot 3\cdot 59=\color{blue}{354}$.

---

Well, now *after* knowing the answer, *and* seeing the factor $59$ in $A$, it becomes natural to compute the height corresponding to the (biggest) side with length $59$. Let $h$ be this (smallest) height, and let $x$, $y$ be the lengths of the projections of the two other sides, $x$ corresponding to $37$, $y$ to $12\sqrt 5$, on this biggest side. Then we can immediately write the system joining $x,y,h$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
59 &= x+y\\
37^2&=x^2+h^2\\
5\cdot 12^2&=y^2+h^2
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Subtracting the last two equation from each other we get
$$
11\cdot 59=649 = 1369-720=x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)\ ,
$$
so $x-y=11$, then $x=(59+11)/2=35$, $y=(59-11)/2=24$ if needed for checks, $h^2=37^2 - 35^2=(37+35)(37-35)=72\cdot 2=144=12^2$, so $h=12$, leading to the known answer for the area, $\displaystyle\frac 12\cdot 12\cdot 59=\color{blue}{354}$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Are you aware of the Heron's formula?

Comment: I am, but I have been thought to think of it only if the sides are rational numbers.

Comment: @Hipo the sides of the triangle do not need to be rational numbers in order to apply the Heron's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Draw altitude $CH$. Then:
$$HA = 59 - C_1H $$
$$144\times5 - C_1H^2 = 37^2 - HA^2 = CH^2 $$
From here find $C_1H$. Then you can find $CH$ and so the area.