# Find the area of a triangle with vertices $(0,1,1),(-1,-1,2),(2,3,1)$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

Find the area of a triangle with vertices $(0,1,1),(-1,-1,2),(2,3,1)$

Using the distance formula, I got that the lengths of the three sides are $a=\sqrt{8},b=\sqrt{6}$ and $c=\sqrt{26}$

Herons formula then states that the Area of the triangle is given by the formula:

$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

Where $s$ is half the perimter:

$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$

After some awful calculations, I came to the conclusion that the area is $\sqrt{3}$.

Is there a shortcut to using Herons formula in this situation? Or is there a shorter way to do this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let us put
$$
\begin{align}
A &:= (-1, -1, 2) \\ 
B &:= (0, 1, 1) \\
C &:= ( 2, 3, 1).
\end{align}
$$
Then the vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are given by
$$
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AB} &= \hat{i} + 2 \hat{j} - \hat{k} \\
\overrightarrow{AC} &= 3\hat{i} + 4 \hat{j} - \hat{k}.
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{AC} &= 
\left| \begin{matrix} \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 3 & 4 & -1 \end{matrix} \right| \\
&= 2 \hat{i} -2 \hat{j} -2\hat{k} \\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore our required area is
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left\lvert \overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{AC} \right\rvert = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ (2)^2 + (-2)^2 + (-2)^2 } = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ 12 } = \frac{1}{2} 2 \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3},
$$
as required.

This method is much shorter than the Heron's formula.

Comment: See also [Intuition behind cross-product and area of parallelogram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666137/intuition-behind-cross-product-and-area-of-parallelogram) & [Area Of Paraellograms & Triangles With Cross Products](https://dk81.github.io/dkmathstats_site/linalg-area-paraellogram.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can express two sides as free vectors $x = (-1,-2,1)$, $y=(2,2,0)$. Then, the area $A$ can also be expressed with dot products (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle)) as
$$
A = \frac12 \sqrt{(xx)(yy) - (xy)^2} \\
= \frac12 \sqrt{6\cdot 8 - (-6)^2} =\frac12 \sqrt{12} = \sqrt{3}
$$
I guess this is the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Heron's formula, and even got for this more than the half of the information, namely $a= \sqrt 8$, $b=\sqrt 6$, $c=\sqrt {26}$, well, OK, then we are quickly done. Note first that
$$
\begin{aligned}
16A^2 &= 16 s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\\
&=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)\cdot (a-b+c)(a+b-c)\\
&=\Big(\ (b+c)^2 -a^2\ \Big)\cdot \Big(\ a^2-(b-c)^2\ \Big)\\
&=\Big(\ 2bc + (b^2+c^2 -a^2)\ \Big)\cdot \Big(\ 2bc-(b^2+c^2 -a^2)\ \Big)\\
&=4b^2c^2-(b^2+c^2 -a^2)^2\\
&=2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2+2a^2b^2-a^4-b^4-c^4\\
&=(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(We can of course stop the computation at the point algebraically involving only squares of $a,b,c$, or use any of the next expressions to evaluate. I felt that the last expression may be easier to evaluate. Or at least it shows the symmetry, someone could have asked for. Well, the above formula is known and useful for applications / explicit computations as in the given case.)
So
$$
16A^2=(8+6+26)^2-2(8^2+6^2+26^2)=48\ ,
$$
leading immediately to $A=\sqrt 3$.